# C++ how can I convert std::vector<std::byte> to const uint8_t *

Tags: c++

The question is explained in the title.

How can I convert `std::vector<std::byte>` to `const uint8_t *` ?

Is this a correct approach:

```
class Packet {
public:
    Packet():
    std::vector<std::byte> body_buffer;
};

void Test(const Packet& packet) {
    flatbuffers::Verifier verifier(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(packet.body_buffer.data()), packet.body_size);
    bool check = Vibranium::VerifyLoginRequestBuffer(verifier);
    if(check){
        Logger::Log("Valid",Logger::LogLevel::Info);
    } else {
        Logger::Log("In valid check",Logger::LogLevel::Info);

    }
}
```

Note: `packet.body_size` is known but not shown in the sample. All is fine with that variable.

Verifier construct takes:

```
class Verifier FLATBUFFERS_FINAL_CLASS {
 public:
  Verifier(const uint8_t *buf, size_t buf_len, uoffset_t _max_depth = 64,
           uoffset_t _max_tables = 1000000, bool _check_alignment = true)
      : buf_(buf),
        size_(buf_len),
        depth_(0),
        max_depth_(_max_depth),
        num_tables_(0),
        max_tables_(_max_tables),
        upper_bound_(0),
        check_alignment_(_check_alignment) {
    FLATBUFFERS_ASSERT(size_ < FLATBUFFERS_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
  }
  ....
```

When I do that it seems it is not correct. Is there any other better way ?
Even when I pass incorrect buffer type it always says it is `Valid` which is not true.

Comment: When I do that it seems it is not correct. What it means? please provide an example of this not correct output.

Answer (score 4):

> C++ how can I convert `std::vector<std::byte>` to `const uint8_t *`
>
> Is this a correct approach:
>
> ```
> flatbuffers::Verifier verifier(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(packet.body_buffer.data()), packet.body_size);
> ```

The conversion can be correct, under these conditions:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<uint8_t, unsigned char>);
assert(packet.body_size <= packet.body_buffer.size());
```

When this is satisfied, `uint8_t` is allowed to alias all other types by virtue of being a name of `unsigned char`. I don't know of a language implementation where `uint8_t` is defined and is not defined as `unsigned char` so this is basically a sanity check that probably never fails.

Comment: So I should put `static_assert(std::is_same_v<uint8_t, unsigned char>);` before `flatbuffers::Verifier verifier(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(packet.body_buffer.data()), packet.body_size);` or `static_assert` returns `bool`?

Comment: @Venelin Just add the static assert as-is anywhere in the source. The program will safely fail to compile in the theoretical case it is not satisfied.

Comment: oh I missed that. But that just reinterprets the contents of the vector as a stream of bytes, no? I mean you can not necessarily compare elements and only making the round trip you are guaranteed to get the original values, or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well, it is a vector of bytes, so such reinterpretation seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @eerorika still i think it is not converting right. When I do that `bool check = Vibranium::VerifyLoginRequestBuffer(verifier);` still returns true which is incorrect.

Comment: @Venelin it is unclear what that checks is checking. Do you actually have any example that passes the test? And btw are you perhaps misinterpreting the result? If a `Verifiyer` returns `true` i'd expect that that means verification passed sucesfully

Comment: @Venelin Regardless, this is how  a `std::vector<std::byte>` is converted to `const uint8_t *`. If that does't do what you want, then you want something more specific that you haven't described.